# Как правильней составить XML файл?

Tags: xml

нужно создать XML файл в котором будет храниться информация о путях к .rtf файлам, иконкам и список изображений. Весь материал разбит на 4 раздела, в которых от 2 до 6 тем. В каждой теме несколько текстов (эти самые .rtf файлы). К каждому тексту прилагается несколько изображений (они показываются отдельно от текста) и у каждого Раздела, Темы и Текста есть иконка, к ней тоже указывается путь.

Вот незнаю как правильно составить, чтобы пользоваться удобно было и понималось легко (другими тоже будет этот файл использоваться потом). Помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы как-то так написал:

```
<big_list>
  <part icon_path="/path/to/icon">
    <theme icon_path="/path/to/icon">
      <text rtf_path="/path/to/rtf/file">
        <image path="/path/to/image">
      </text>
      <text rtf_path="/path/to/rtf/file"/>
    </theme>
  </part>
<big_list>
```

Иконка у раздела (темы или текста) может быть только одна -- пишем ее значение в атрибут. Тестов и изображений может быть много -- сохраняем их в виде узлов.